# Android: setImageBitmap for ImageView causes crash

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, setimagebitmap

I am trying to set Image Bitmap of an ImageView to a bitmap. Here is the code:

```
my_image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp_image = getOutputBitmap();
my_image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);
```

The `getOutputBitmap` reads an image and returns a bitmap. However, the 3rd line of the code, i.e `my_image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);` causes the app to crash.

Does the `bmp_image` need to have any specific format or properties? The crash does not come from a `null` value for `bmp_image` as I see it is not null in debug mode, actually, it is a real image and I can watch it in debug mode.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: And what the crash about ? "post stack trace"

Comment: In the log-cat you can find which problem happened, btw why the problem should be in line 3?

Comment: The problem is in line 3 because when I comment that line out, the app does not crash. Shall I choose "Android Monitor" to see log-cat?

Comment: yup, if your `getOutpuBitmap()` do it work as well, there would be no problem indeed.

Comment: Here is a good place start https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is not in your third line for setup a Bitmap but I think your method returning null bitmap so before checking null condition it will not crash,
 like following

```
my_image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bmp_image = getOutputBitmap();
if(bmp_image!=null)
  my_image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp_image);
```

Comment: Actually, I am sure the method is fine because in debug mode I can click on the bmp_image in "watch" and see the image.

Comment: Can you put here your log crash so we can check.

Comment: Is there a way I can store log-cat crash?

Comment: Yes, You can put try catch and store it in file.